# Eliminar v1 en url de endpoint

Tags: java, webservice, rest, google-app-engine, endpoint

Estoy usando GAE para generar Servlets y todo funciona perfectamente, sin embargo a la ruta de los endpoint siempre les agrega un "v1" el cual quiero quitar, este es un ejemplo de como queda la ruta:

> https://xxxxx.appspot.com/services/test/v1/imprimirPersona?n=5

y quiero que quedé de la siguiente forma:

> https://xxxxx.appspot.com/services/test/imprimirPersona?n=5

pero no sé como lograrlo.

Web.xml :

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
<!-- Wrap the backend with Endpoints Frameworks v2. -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>services</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.skeleton.MyApi,
        com.example.skeleton.Foo</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<!-- Route API method requests to the backend. -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

MyApi.class:

```
@Api(name = "test")
public class MyApi {

@ApiMethod(name = "datosPorUrl", httpMethod = "GET")
public Message datosPorUrl(Message message, @Named("n") @Nullable Integer n) {
    message.setMessage("El valor recibido es : " + n);
    return message;
}

@ApiMethod(name = "imprimirPersona", httpMethod = "POST")
public Message imprimirPersona(Persona persona, @Named("n") @Nullable Integer n) {
    Message message = new Message();
    message.setMessage("Test :  El valor nombre es : " + persona.getNombre()
            + " la edad es : " + persona.getEdad());
    return message;
}
}
```

Comment: Por qué quieres quitarlo? Es una buena idea el definir versiones del API, por si un día quieres crear un nuevo API manteniendo el antiguo por temas de compatibilidad.

Comment: @PabloLozano El cliente requiere una ruta especifica :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lograrlo tuve que agregar el path manualmente de la siguiente forma :

```
@ApiMethod(..., path = "/test/imprimirPersona")
```

Answer (score 0):

Según la [documentación de Google](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/annotations), la anotación `@Api` tiene un atributo opcional llamado `defaultVersion` cuyo valor por defecto es `true`:

> Specifies whether a default version is used if none is supplied in the
>   version attribute.

En principio, si este valor es `false`, no se debería usar ningún valor por defecto como versión.

Comment: Acabo de intentarlo, pero no funcionó :/